# PHP and MySQL Format the output

Tags: php, html, mysql, datetime, format

I am trying to format data from my MySQL database on a php HTML site.
The date in MySQL looks like the following

```
2015-07-10 03:17:00
```

I would like to have it formatted like this

```
10-07-2015 03:17
```

It will then be display in a HTML form as below

```
<td>Open MT4 Time:</td>
<td><input type="datetime-local" name="openmt4time" value="<?php echo $row['openmt4time']; ?>"</td>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this for format dates:

```
$date = $row['DateFromDB'];
$fecha = new DateTime($date);
$newdate = $fecha->format('d-m-Y H:i');
echo $newdate;
```

That should help too!

Comment: Hi, sorry I made a mistake.  The format for it to work it ":1996-12-19T16:39:57".  Do you know how to do this ?

Answer (score 3):

$row['openmt4time'] = date_format($row['openmt4time'],"d-m-Y H:i");

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it with the `date();` function.

`date("d-m-Y H:i", strtotime($row['openmt4time']));`

This should ouput the format you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

1. To format the date with MySQL you can use the function DATE_FORMAT()

   SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`your_date_column_name`,'%d %m %Y %h:%i') AS `openmt4time` FROM `table_name`

Now the $row['openmt4time'] will be having the formated date. Just echo it.

Learn about more date formats [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-date_format/)

2. In PHP you can format the date by using the date function as follows
   `date("d-m-Y H:i", strtotime($your_non_formated_date_string));`

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

if your format is

```
$YOUR_DATE = '2015-07-20 09:05';
date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($YOUR_DATE));
```

if your format is

```
$YOUR_DATE = '20-07-2015 09:05';
date('d-m-Y H:i', strtotime($YOUR_DATE));
```